# Unity "Broken text PPtr - Local file identifier doesn't exist" error in scene file after merging

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I resolve this build-only error that appeared in my `dev` builds after merging in some branches?

```
Broken text PPtr in file(Assets/Scenes/ActivitySelect.unity). Local file identifier (759292172) doesn't exist!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, the issue appeared because some prefabs were changed and it left the scene with some bad pointers.

I just had to "sync" the file to have the scene file repair itself.

Steps:

- add an empty `GameObject`
- delete the empty `GameObject`
- save the scene

[image: diff-after-sync]